# Entity Framework connection string for update-database

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I can't figure out how to handle connection strings in EF and NetCore

I have a solution with `EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.7` and two projects:

```
WebApp.csproj
ShraedLibrary.csproj
   - appsettings.json
```

All data connection stuffs are in `ShraedLibrary`, where I have this constructors:

```
public DatabaseContext (DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options, ILoggerProvider loggerProvider)
```

This works fine, but I cannot `Update-Database` using the connection string from `appsettings.json` because there is no parameterless constructor.

When I hardcode the connection string inside a parameterless constructor then it works

What is the right way of doing this?

[EDIT]

Don't use `-Project` in `Update-Database` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you need to create [`IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TContext>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.idesigntimedbcontextfactory-1?view=efcore-3.1).

EntityFramework Core migrations works by running your code, if that isn't possible (as it is your case with the shared library), then you need to provide more information about how your DbContext could be created. For that purpose you can use this `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TContext>` factory.

Comment: Why can't my code be run? what is the difference for it to be in a library? - I will check the IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TContext> now. Thanks! :)

Comment: Your library doesn't have access to the startup of you app, where you have configured the DbContext (in the `ConfigureServices(...)` method). So, it doesn't know from where to get the connection string.

Comment: why it cannot? Should't it work if I do `Update-Database -StartupProject WebApp -Project SharedLibrary` ?

Comment: How have you configured EF in the services? Can you try using CLI, not PMC. Also, what error it gives you?

Comment: I figured out, you don't need to do `-Project ` but only `-StartupProject`. Your answer pointed me in the right direction, Thanks!